# Create custom Shape Control in UWP (Universal Windows Apps), Windows 10

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app, template-control

I want to create a custom `Shape` control, that paints different shapes like `Polygon`, `Ellipse`, `Rectangle`, etc, depending on some custom properties.

I was able to create a custom template control `ColorShape` like this:

```
<Style TargetType="local:CustomShape">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="local:CustomShape">
                <ContentControl x:Name="shapeParent">
                </ContentControl>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

And then, override the `OnTemplateChanged` method, and insert a corresponding `Shape` control inside the `shapeParent` `ContentControl`

But what I'd like is to actually extend the `Shape`, so I can treat all the shapes, framewok and custom, in the same way.

In WPF we were able to extend the `Shape` and override the property `DefiningGeometry`.
In UWP it doesn´t exist any `DefiningGeometry` property to override.

How is it possible to create a custom `Shape` control and define the corresponding Geometry?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only way I found to create custom shapes in UWP is to extend the [`Path`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/apps/br243355) class and set its [`Data`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.path.data) property.

Updating the `Data` property to account for changes in other dependency properties (like `Width`) must not be done in layouting relevant sections, like the `LayoutUpdated` event or the `ArrangeOverride` method.

Setting `Data` leads to another layout run, so setting it in anything that is called during that would lead to an exception:

> Layout cycle detected. Layout could not complete

The way I use is to register handler for property changed events and update `Data` in them.

I have written a [blog post](http://domysee.com/blogposts/Blogpost%207%20-%20Creating%20custom%20Shapes%20for%20UWP%20Apps/) that explains it in a bit more detail.

This is the example I used:

```
public class CandlestickShape : Path
{
    public double StartValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(GetValue(StartValueProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(StartValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty StartValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("StartValue", typeof(double), typeof(CandlestickShape), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public double EndValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(GetValue(EndValueProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(EndValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EndValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("EndValue", typeof(double), typeof(CandlestickShape), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public double MinValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(GetValue(MinValueProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(MinValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MinValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MinValue", typeof(double), typeof(CandlestickShape), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public double MaxValue
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(GetValue(MaxValueProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(MaxValueProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MaxValueProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("MaxValue", typeof(double), typeof(CandlestickShape), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    /// <summary>
    /// Defines how many Pixel should be drawn for one Point
    /// </summary>
    public double PixelPerPoint
    {
        get { return Convert.ToDouble(GetValue(PointsPerPixelProperty)); }
        set { SetValue(PointsPerPixelProperty, value); }
    }
    public static readonly DependencyProperty PointsPerPixelProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("PixelPerPoint", typeof(double), typeof(CandlestickShape), new PropertyMetadata(0));

    public CandlestickShape()
    {
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.WidthProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.StartValueProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.EndValueProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.MinValueProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.MaxValueProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
        this.RegisterPropertyChangedCallback(CandlestickShape.PointsPerPixelProperty, new DependencyPropertyChangedCallback(RenderAffectingPropertyChanged));
    }

    private void RenderAffectingPropertyChanged(DependencyObject o, DependencyProperty e)
    {
        (o as CandlestickShape)?.SetRenderData();
    }

    private void SetRenderData()
    {
        var maxBorderValue = Math.Max(this.StartValue, this.EndValue);
        var minBorderValue = Math.Min(this.StartValue, this.EndValue);
        double topLineLength = (this.MaxValue - maxBorderValue) * this.PixelPerPoint;
        double bottomLineLength = (minBorderValue - this.MinValue) * this.PixelPerPoint;
        double bodyLength = (this.EndValue - this.StartValue) * this.PixelPerPoint;

        var fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Green);
        if (bodyLength < 0)
            fillColor = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red);

        bodyLength = Math.Abs(bodyLength);

        var bodyGeometry = new RectangleGeometry
        {
            Rect = new Rect(new Point(0, topLineLength), new Point(this.Width, topLineLength + bodyLength)),
        };

        var topLineGeometry = new LineGeometry
        {
            StartPoint = new Point(this.Width / 2, 0),
            EndPoint = new Point(this.Width / 2, topLineLength)
        };

        var bottomLineGeometry = new LineGeometry
        {
            StartPoint = new Point(this.Width / 2, topLineLength + bodyLength),
            EndPoint = new Point(this.Width / 2, topLineLength + bodyLength + bottomLineLength)
        };

        this.Data = new GeometryGroup
        {
            Children = new GeometryCollection
            {
                bodyGeometry,
                topLineGeometry,
                bottomLineGeometry
            }
        };
        this.Fill = fillColor;
        this.Stroke = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Black);
    }

    protected override Size ArrangeOverride(Size finalSize)
    {
        double height = (MaxValue - MinValue) * PixelPerPoint;
        return new Size(this.Width, height);
    }

    protected override Size MeasureOverride(Size availableSize)
    {
        double height = (MaxValue - MinValue) * PixelPerPoint;
        return new Size(this.Width, height);
    }
}
```

Comment: That covers your use case, but what happens when you want a custom shame with some parts that are fixed points and others that depend on the size, like this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43761186/how-to-create-a-speech-bubble-in-uwp The rectangle part depends on the size, but the pointed part is fixed.