# Class derived from shape gives cast error

Tags: c#, uwp

I have a class in a UWP Project that derives from Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape:

```
public class Hex : Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape
{
    public Hex()
    {

    }
}
```

When I tried to instantiate a new memeber of this class in mainPage.cs I get an InvalidCastException as following:

```
System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
       at Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape..ctor()
       at App1.Hex..ctor()
       at App1.MainPage.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
```

Here is the code from mainPage.cs

```
private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var h = new Hex();
    h.Width = 20;
}
```

but doesn't work neither. As I understand the protected constructor of Shape should be able to be accessed from a derived class, so what's happening? Doing the same thing with deriving from Windows.UI.Xaml.Frameworkelemnt works without problems.

Comment: We are going to need to see the code, for both classes constructors at least.

Comment: What is the constructor for `Shape`?

Comment: The Shape class is the one Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape,

Comment: Are you sure you are not deriving your class accidentally from `System.Windows.Shapes.Shape` rather than `System.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape`? Change your class declaration to be fully qualified with the namespace and see if it works: `public class Hex : System.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape { ... }`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and the stack trace. I can't see how `Hex hex = new Hex();` could ever throw an `InvalidCastException` as there are no casts involved in any of the code you've shown.

Comment: Yes, I just rechecked. It UI.Xaml. I made it totally simple to find the problem, but stuck. Its just the derived class in an UWP Project and I try to instantiate a new parameterless Hex from the mainPage.cs. As said it works if I I take another class with no proteced constructer ro derive... So this seems to be the problem, but its callint the constructor from shape though

Comment: I updated the sample above. I just made the sample as simple as possible. Its  just the derived class and something (a button in mainPage.cs in this case) that should create a new instance of the class.

Comment: Okay, I've reproduced the problem now. Very odd. Looking into it a bit... I can only think at the moment that it's trying to fetch some property and cast the result. It's hard to tell what though.

Comment: The stack trace says the code in the constrcutor [`protected Shape()` (docs link)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.shapes.shape.-ctor) (which is necesaarily chained since it is the only visible instance constructor) attempts an invalid cast (possibly a bad unboxing into a value type, I do not know). So we need to look at the source code for this member of `Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.dll` (?) before we can answer. Is this source code open?

Answer (score 1):

TLDR;  It's not possible without some serious hurt.  But...  IT IS POSSIBLE.

I started out by reproducing the problem, here's the stack trace to prove it:

```
   at Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape..ctor()
   at App1.Hex..ctor()
   at App1.App1_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider.Activate_0_Hex()
   at App1.App1_XamlTypeInfo.XamlUserType.ActivateInstance()
```

You can see that the type providers for the xaml elements (`App1_XamlTypeInfo`) are generated at run-time, thus you cannot override those [Factory|Instance Creation|Builder] methods with customised code.

Not even an attempt to create an implicit conversion in the Hex class to the Shape type could fix it, apparently a limitation of C# that you cannot make a custom implicit conversion from sub-class to base-class, because "it changes already compiled code" or whatever :(

Another route could have been to *favour encapsulation over inheritance*, you'd be required to re-implement/expose the Shape class in all its glory and manipulate an internal Shape instance, however there'll be a limitation in that you cannot implement the IShape and IShape2 interfaces from WPF, because they're marked internal.

As far as I can tell, the only option left is to modify the WPF source code, and distribute that...  I have no idea on licensing issues related to doing such things.  See https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/Windows/Shapes/Shape.cs  for the class that you'd need to change, or just include your own derived type (like `Ellipse`), and https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/PresentationFramework.csproj just to point out that it's quite easy to build *citation needed*.

Hopefully someone else comes along and proves me wrong...

Answer (score 1):

I don't understand this either; it's quite annoying but apparently you can't derive from `Shape` as you'd expect (and should be able to do.)  Instead you have to inherit from `Path` and add the paths that way.  I'll link another answer here on SO that explains it better rather than duplicate.

[Answered already on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35697991/create-custom-shape-control-in-uwp-universal-windows-apps-windows-10)

Comment: Thank you for your answers. So I will do it with Path class... At least I know now that I'm not the only one who cannot inherit from class shape

Answer (score 1):

> When I tried to instantiate a new memeber of this class in mainPage.cs
>   I get an InvalidCastException as following:
>
> ```
> System.InvalidCastException: Specified cast is not valid.
>        at Windows.UI.Xaml.Shapes.Shape..ctor()
>        at App1.Hex..ctor()
>        at App1.MainPage.Button_Click(Object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
> ```

Thank you for your feedback. We fully understand that this exception may cause confusion.

The fact is, even though Shape is unsealed, creating a custom shape that way isn't supported.

To draw custom shapes, please use the existing Shape types.

For example, a hex shape can be easily created using a Polygon with 6 vertices:

```
<Polygon
    Points="143,75 143,125 100,150 57,125 57,75 100,50"
    Stroke="Blue"                
    Fill="LightBlue" />
```

For more complicated shapes, customers can instead use the Path class as described here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/design/controls-and-patterns/shapes#path

If desired you can then wrap any shape in a custom control, for example using a UserControl:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.usercontrol

Comment: Thank you, Franklin. Polygon would have been first choice you are right, but I need to add some custom dp (and there is no way to do to a existing class without deriving, right?) and as I need a lot of Hexes my try with ContentControl and Polygon as content made everything to slow. So first idea was to take the closest to Polygon for deriving...